# What are nested functions? What are they for?

Tags: information-hiding, nested-function

I've never used nested functions, but have seen references to them in several languages (as well as nested classes, which I assume are related).

- What is a nested function?
- Why?!?
- What can you do with a nested function that you cannot do any other way?
- What can you do with a nested function this is difficult or inelegant without nested functions?

I assume nested functions are simply an artifact of treating everything as an object, and if objects can contain other objects then it follows.

Do nested functions have scope (in general, I suppose languages differ on this) just as variables inside a function have scope?

Please add the language you are referencing if you're not certain that your answer is language agnostic.

-Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One popular use of nested functions is [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). In a [lexically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)#Static_scoping_.28also_known_as_lexical_scoping.29) language with first-class functions it's possible to use functions to store data. A simple example in Scheme is a counter:

```
(define (make-counter)
  (let ((count 0))                ; used to store the count
    (define (counter)             ; this is the counter we're creating
      (set! count (+ count 1))    ; increment the count
      count)                      ; return the new count
    counter))                     ; return the new counter function

(define mycounter (make-counter)) ; create a counter called mycounter

(mycounter)                       ; returns 1

(mycounter)                       ; returns 2
```

In this example, we nest the function counter inside the function make-counter, and by returning this internal function we are able to access the data available to counter when it was defined. This information is private to this instance of mycounter - if we were to create another counter, it would use a different spot to store the internal count. Continuing from the previous example:

```
(define mycounter2 (make-counter))

(mycounter2)                      ; returns 1

(mycounter)                       ; returns 3
```

Answer (score 3):

It's useful for recursion when there is only 1 method that will ever call it

```
string[] GetFiles(string path)
{
  void NestedGetFiles(string path, List<string> result)
  {
    result.AddRange( files in the current path);
    foreach(string subPath in FoldersInTheCurrentPath)
      NestedGetFiles(subPath, result);
  }

   List<string> result = new List<string>();
   NestedGetFiles(path, result);
   return result.ToArray();
}
```

The above code is completely made up but is based on C# to give the idea of what I mean.  The only method that can call NestedGetFiles is the GetFiles method.

Answer (score 2):

Nested functions allow you to encapsulate code that is only relevant to the inner workings of one function within that function, while still allowing you to separate that code out for readability or generalization.  In some implementations, they also allow access to outer scope.  In D:

```
int doStuff() {
    int result;
    void cleanUpReturn() {
        myResource1.release();
        myResource2.release();
        return result * 2 + 1;
    }

    auto myResource1 = getSomeResource();
    auto myResource2 = getSomeOtherResource();
    if(someCondition) {
        return cleanUpReturn();
    } else {
        doSomeOtherStuff();
        return cleanUpReturn();
    }
}
```

Of course, in this case this could also be handled with RAII, but it's just a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

A nested function is simply a function defined within the body of another function.  Why?  About the only reason I could think of off the top of my head is a helper or utility function.

This is a contrived example but bear with me.  Let's say you had a function that had to act on the results two queries and fill an object with values from one of the queries.  You could do something like the following.

```
function process(qryResult q1, qryResult q2) {

   object o;
   if (q1.someprop == "useme") {
       o.prop1 = q1.prop1;
       o.prop2 = q1.prop2;
       o.prop3 = q1.prop3;
   } else if (q2.someprop == "useme") {
       o.prop1 = q2.prop1;
       o.prop2 = q2.prop2;
       o.prop3 = q2.prop3;
   }

   return o;

}
```

If you had 20 properties, you're duplicating the code to set the object over and over leading to a huge function.  You could add a simple nested function to do the copy of the properties from the query to the object.  Like this:

```
function process(qryResult q1, qryResult q2) {

   object o;
   if (q1.someprop == "useme") {
       fillObject(o,q1);
   } else if (q2.someprop == "useme") {
       fillObject(o,q2);
   }

   return o;

   function fillObject(object o, qryResult q) {
       o.prop1 = q.prop1;
       o.prop2 = q.prop2;
       o.prop3 = q.prop3;
   }


}
```

It keeps things a little cleaner.  Does it have to be a nested function?  No, but you may want to do it this way if the process function is the only one that would have to do this copy.

Answer (score 1):

(C#) :
I use that to simplify the Object Browser view, and to structure my classes better.
As class Wheel nested in Truck class.

Don't forget this detail :
"Nested types can access private and protected members of the containing type, including any inherited private or protected members."

Answer (score 1):

A nested function is just a function inside another function.

Yes, it is a result of everything being an object.  Since you can have variables only visible in the function's scope and variables can point to functions you can have a function that is referenced by a local variable.

I don't think there is anything that you can do with a nested function that you absolutely couldn't do without. A lot of the times it makes sense, though.  Namely, whenever a function is a "sub-function" of some other function.

A common use-case for me is when a function performs a lot of complicated logic but what the function computes/returns is easy to abstract for all the cases dictated by the logic.

Answer (score 1):

They can also be useful if you need to pass a function to another function as an argument.  They can also be useful for making factory functions for factory functions (in Python):

```
>>> def GetIntMaker(x):
...   def GetInt():
...     return x
...   return GetInt
... 
>>> GetInt = GetIntMaker(1)
>>> GetInt()
1
```